# Opencart 3, composer install dompdf

Tags: composer-php, opencart, dompdf

How can I use composer to install dompdf, and load this into a controller class in opencart 3.

I have tried to use composer require dompdf... however this doesn't work, I'm not sure what directory this needs to be run in

Answer (score 0):

In your `composer.json` file, add the Dompdf package:

```
{
    "require": {
        "dompdf/dompdf": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

And then run: `composer update`

To use `DOMPDF` in an opencart controller, all you have to do is:

```php
<?php
class ControllerExampleEmail extends Controller {

    public function index() {

        $dompdf = new DOMPDF(); 

    }

}
```

It's auto-loaded by OpenCart itself.

Comment: Thank you! That works as expected if I'm using dompdf from a standalone php file, I'm struggling with how I can load this into a controller class inside opencart, any ideas?

Comment: Thats what I thought! it just gives my a 500 error :/

Comment: Nothing in the error logs, it's just a HTTP 500 error, here's the code.

Comment: <?php
class ControllerCommonHome extends Controller {
 public function index() {
        $dompdf = new DOMPDF();

Comment: Please follow the following instructions to retrieve the error: https://isenselabs.com/posts/500-internal-server-error-opencart

Also check out the "Frequent Cases & Possible Solutions" found in the article.

Answer (score 0):

Only really posting this as an answer to get the formatting, but I was just looking at exactly the same thing (adding DOMPDF to OpenCart 3) and (having already done the composer bit) have gotten this far (which will spit out a PDF):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<modification>
    <name>DOMPDF Test</name>
    <code>dompdftest</code>
    <version>3.0.3x</version>
    <author>TH</author>
    <link></link>
    <file path="system/library/response.php">
        <operation error="abort">
            <comment>Use the class</comment>
            <search><![CDATA[class Response {]]></search>
            <add position="before"><![CDATA[
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation error="abort">
            <comment>Output to PDF instead of HTML</comment>
            <search><![CDATA[private $output;]]></search>
            <add position="after"><![CDATA[
  // TH
    public function writePDF($input,$filename) {
    $dompdf = new Dompdf();
    $dompdf->loadHtml($input);
    $dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');
    $dompdf->render();
    $dompdf->stream($filename);
  }
  // /TH
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
</modification>
```

Have only tested this insofar as it spits out a PDF, it could well be wrong/not the best way to do it.